# Database for large data files and streaming

Tags: database, mongodb, hadoop, bigdata

I have a "database choice" and arhitecture question.

**Use-case**:

1. Clients will **upload** large .json files (or other format like .tsv, it is irrelevant) where each line is a data about their customers (e.g name, address etc.)
2. We need to **stream** this data later on to process it and **store** results which will also be some large file where each line is data about each customer (approximately same as uploaded file).

**My requirements**:

1. Streaming should be as fast it could (e.g > 1000 rps) and we could have multiple process running in parallel (for multiple clients)
2. Database should be scalable and fault tolerant. Because there could easily be uploaded many GB of data it should be easy for me to implement automatically adding new commodity instances (using AWS) if storage gets low.
3. Database should have kind of replication because we don't want to lose data.
4. No index is required since we are just streaming data.

What would you suggest for database for this problem? We tried to upload it to Amazon S3 and let them take care of scaling etc. but there is a problem of slow read/streaming.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: What you need is data store rather than database. Even plain simple HDFS should be OK for your use-case. Are you looking for solutions in the cloud or on-premise cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially uploading the files to S3 is fine, but then pick them up and push each line to Kinesis (or MSK or even Kafka on EC2s if you prefer); from there, you can hook up the stream processing framework of your choice (Flink, Spark Streaming, Samza, Kafka Streams, Kinesis KCL) to do transformations and enrichment, and finally you’ll want to pipe the results into a storage stack that will allow streaming appends. A few obvious candidates:

- HBase
- Druid
- Keyspaces for Cassandra
- Hudi (or maybe LakeFS?) on top of S3

Which one you choose is kind of up to your needs downstream in terms of query flexibility, latency, integration options/standards, etc.